# new list data type

Tags: sml, smlnj

how can I define new data type in ML, let's assume newList, such that it can consist lists of element 'a (int, real, etc.), nested lists, for example:
if my type 'a is int, values may be: [1], [1,[4]], [1,[5],[[5]]], etc.
thanks in advance for any help

**EDITED**
sorry without 1 in the example, different lists of int, I deleted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. All elements in a list must be of the same type. In your example, some of the elements are of `int` type, and some are `int list`.

You can create something like this tree, but the syntax is not so nice to use :-)

```
datatype 'a multiList = Empty
                      | List of 'a multiList list
                      | E of 'a;

val x = List [E 1, List [E 1, List [E 4]], List [E 1, List [E 5]]];
```

Comment: @rookie, I've updated my answer so it contains a polymorphic tree :-) Btw, I have examination in Standard ML tomorrow. It's nice to exercise a little :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
datatype 'a multiList = E of 'a
                      | List of 'a multiList list
```

Your examples would be:

```
List [E 1]

List [E 1, List [E 4]]

List [E 1, List [E 5], List [List [E 5]]]
```